# Node JS/localhost server is not showing the image

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I created localhost/server on node js, and my pictures/img tag doesn't work

```
   <div class="text-center">
     <img alt = "Bulb" src="pic_bulboff.gif" class="rounded" alt="bulboff">
   </div>
```

but the problem is that they show up when I open them in a regular browser without the server

```
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')
const port = 3000

const server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
    fs.readFile('index.html', function(error, data) {
        if(error)   {  
            res.writeHead(404)
            res.write('Error: File not Found')
        } else {
            res.write(data)
        }
        res.end();
    })
})
```

above is the node server.

is there a problem that I can't really see?

Thanks!!!

Comment: When you open up the file in the browser, take that URL and put in in the `src` attribute. Does it then render?

Comment: If that is your entire server js file, then you haven't setup how the server should serve the image files

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-serve-static-files/

Answer (score 0):

By default a nodejs http server does not serve ANY files at all.  You've created an http server that serves `index.html` for ALL incoming requests.  So, a browser makes a request from your web server and you send it the HTML content from `index.html`.

Then, the browser parses that HTML and sees an `<img>` tag with a `src` attribute of `"pic_bulboff.gif"` so the browser then sends a request to your web server asking it for the content for `/pick_bulboff.gif`.  But, you web server just responds to that request by sending `index.html`.  That obviously doesn't work.  You need your web server to know the difference between different path requests so it will server `index.html` when the browser is requesting `/`, but will serve that image when the browser is requesting `/pick_bulboff.gif`.

While most people will use a simple web framework that has the serving of static files as a built-in feature (like the Express framework), you can do it manually if you want:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const port = 3000;

function sendFile(fname, contentType) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType});
    fs.readFile(fname, function(error, data) {
        if(error)   {  
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.write('Error: File not Found');
        } else {
            res.write(data);
        }
        res.end();
    }
}

const server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    if (req.url === "/") {
        sendFile('index.html', 'text/html');
    } else if (req.url === '/pick_bulboff.gif') {
        sendFile('pick_bulboff.gif', 'image/gif');
    } else {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end('Error: Unsupported path');
    }
});

server.listen(port);
```

In a more typical implementation, you would put all static files in one directory  hierarchy that was separate from your code and you would use functionality similar to `express.static()` in the Express framework to serve any file in that static files directory that matches an incoming request so you don't have to create a custom route for every single static file you're using in your project.